# SwiftUI Binding Error: Why does this not work?

Tags: swiftui

I am facing issues setting up `Binding` in the following SwiftUI code snippet. I am trying this on xCode Beta 7 ((11M392r).

In the code snippet below, I am creating 2 Stepper views.

If I pass `$student.totalMarks` to Stepper, it works and creates the right Binding.

But if I try to access `$student.marks.score1`, that does not work and shows the following compilation error:

`Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred`.

Is there a way to pass single field from a nested property into a binding?

```
struct Marks {
    public let score1: Int
    public let score2: Int
    public let score3: Int
}

class Student: ObservableObject {
    @Published var totalMarks: Int = 145
    @Published var marks = Marks(score1: 67, score2: 56, score3: 64)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var student = Student()

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Stepper("Total Score: \(student.totalMarks)", value: $student.totalMarks)
            Stepper("Score 1: \(student.marks.score1)", value: $student.marks.score1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. ;-) Don't use a constant for a stepper's value binding. Rather make your scores variables (using `var` instead of `let` in struct `Marks`).